# How do I delete/update files in Google Compute Engine

Tags: file, google-compute-engine, python-3.6

I have everything set up so that my discord bot runs on Google Cloud, but my only problem is that I can't seem to figure out how to update or delete files on the cloud disk drive. I am searching everywhere and I can't seem to find it. This bugs me because now I have to completely rename my bot every time I upload it or else I can't run it. This issue is really hurting my coding because I want to move forward, but I am very thorough and this issue will haunt me if I just leave it be.

I found the answer finally and to edit files you have to use vi, vim, or nano in the terminal. To remove the files you have to use rm. I think Google should make a better way to access the directory and edit my disk without having to use command lines, but I doubt they will.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that GCP only offers e virtual infrastructure (for Compute Engine). The VM still runs a regular Operating System (with certain files pre packaged in to make sure it works with the cloud environment). Management of the operating system is still up to the user.

You can use something like [App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine) if you only want to manage and update the code for your application.

Alternatively, you can also use [gcloud compute scp](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/scp) to copy files from a local system directly to the VM.